# Get URL of file in .jar that the program is running

Tags: java, url

Given hello.jar, which is compiled with maven, I want to access a resource located under folder/file.file. However I don't know how to get the URL of the current JAR I am in. Would

```
file://./folder/file.file
```

work correctly, or,

```
jar:file://./!hello.jar/folder/file.file
```

or is there an easier way to do this?

(Sorry for the dumb question, I'm new to maven.)

Comment: Where is the resource located? In the `jar`? Where are you locating in from, the program of maven?

Comment: The resource is within the jar (in the source code, it's under src/main/resources/folder/file.file) and I'm locating from the program under src/main/java/package/package/package/file.java. So yeah.

Comment: In that case JohnKlehm is correct.

Comment: This is the correct syntax for a JAR file in the current directory: `jar:file:hello.jar!/folder/file.file`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
String jarPath = URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile(), "UTF-8");
```

`jarPath` then contains the complete path to the jar file where the class with that code is located.

Note the "detour" through URLDecoder, otherwise you'll get a filename containing %20 if the jar files is located in a directory that contains spaces.

Comment: This worked for me. To get a file within the jar I did: `String jarPath = URLDecoder.decode(rawurl.getFile(), "UTF-8");
        URL imgurl = new URL("file://" + jarPath + "folder/file.file")`

Answer (score 3):

You can find a jar's resources by using:

```
String resRelativePath = "folder/thing.jpg";
URL resUrl = this.getClass().getResource(resRelativePath);
```

Comment: This gives me an error with the following lines:         `String resRelativePath = "folder/file.file";
        URL resUrl = this.getClass().getResource(resRelativePath);
        System.out.println(resUrl.getPath());` I get a nullpointerexception on the final line...I'm probably missing something stupid

Comment: Add leading slash to `folder/thing.jpg`  -->  `/folder/thing.jpg`, to find file within `src/main/resources/`. It is because you use `Class#getResource()` method which search in `src/main/resources/` if you use absolute path. If you use relative path, then it is look up relative to class from which method is invoked.