# MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE when running project from exported JAR file

Tags: java, javafx, executable-jar

This is not a duplicate, because Media objects cannot be initialized with getResourceAsStream(). From the docs: "only HTTP, FILE, and JAR URIs are supported."

My JavaFX project works perfectly when I run it from Eclipse, but breaks when I run the executable JAR that I export. I have tried each type of library handling, but none of it works. I'm using JavaFX 2.2 and Eclipse Oxygen March 2018.

```
public static Media gameMusic;
public static MediaPlayer gameMusicPlayer;
public static MediaView gameMusicMediaView;

// adds music, once for each audio file to be played
gameMusic = new Media(new File("resources/data/music/Kevin_MacLeod_-_Ouroboros_-_Full_Mix.wav").toURI().toString());
bulletSound = new AudioClip(new File("resources/data/music/Photon gun shot.wav").toURI().toString());
explosionSound = new AudioClip(new File("resources/data/music/Explosion+3.wav").toURI().toString());
```

The directory structure:

```
+src
  -source files
+resources
  +data
    +music
      -music files
    +fxml
      -fxml files
    +other folders
```

The error output:

```
MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : /Users/username/Desktop/resources/data/music/Kevin_MacLeod_-_Ouroboros_-_Full_Mix.wav (No such file or directory)
at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:407)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:77)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

Note: when I fixed the code for the filepaths to include the executable's name, it breaks in both Eclipse and the executable

Comment: You need to know the absolute root of the folder where resources are stored, otherwise you cannot find them. Gradle offers a `application` plugin which will create a Windows, Linux and Mac script that will pass the current directory as its first argument. You might also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java

Comment: There is no other folder. All of this is getting exported into a single jar file

Comment: @AndrewS just saw your note, Did you try `refer` method? And are your resources placed in same package directory?

Comment: When you deploy the JAR file, how do you deploy the WAV files? Are they packaged inside the JAR file? Or are they copied along with the JAR file?

Comment: If you are packaging the WAV files inside the JAR file, then you need to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar

Comment: @UsamaAmjad I am not familiar with the `refer` method.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The exported executable jar has two source folders: `src` & `resources`. The WAVs are stored in `resources`. When I export, I've been telling it to extract the required libraries into the JAR

Comment: If your resources are packaged into the jar you should  call `getResource("foo.wav").toString()` on the `class` to get the resource URL.

Comment: Check the links at the top of this page for suggestions about how to read files inside a JAR file.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I edited to explain why this is not a duplicate

Comment: @AndrewS read the first link again. It shows how to obtain a jar uri.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I must be blind because I only see an example of how to get a file as an InputStream, with no explanation of how to get a URI from said InputStream

Comment: @AndrewS you get a uri for a file inside a jar. No input stream needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16240426/1440565

Answer (score -1):

The error is pretty simple that it says `MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE` means that your project is unable to find the resources from the given path. It is probably due to the relative path, you need to provide an Absolute path to find resources from the system.

You could try something like this

```
Media media = new Media(getHostServices().getDocumentBase() + "/com/projectName/resources/hello.mp3");
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

**EDIT**

From the hostServices.getCodeBase() [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#getCodeBase--):

> If the application is not packaged in a jar file, this method returns the empty string.

And make sure you have proper `imports` and extended your app with `Application` class

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.HostServices;

public class App extends Application {

}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but it threw another error:

Comment: `MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : /Users/andrewsneed/Desktop/com/Escape!/resources/data/music/Kevin_MacLeod_-_Ouroboros_-_Full_Mix.wav (No such file or directory)
 at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:407)
 at application.Main.start(Main.java:77)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)`

Comment: @AndrewS check the updated answer.

Comment: the updated answer did not help, and the imported libraries were never used. Any other ideas?